# Calculations in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I have something like:

```
    [
{
    ....
    a: 100
    b: 60
},
{
    ....
    a: 130
    b: 40
},
{
    ....
    a: 120
    b: 60
}
]
```

and I want to compute:
sum(a)/sum(b): (350/160) and put it in a new field
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can do the update using the Update with Aggregation Pipeline functionality. There are aggregation arithmetic operators to do the computation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should use `$group` to get sum of all a and b (group by `_id:1`), then use `$project` to get `a/b` ([Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Su2wX59VCzp)):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": 1,
      "sumA": {
        "$sum": "$a"
      },
      "sumB": {
        "$sum": "$b"
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "aDIVb": {
        "$divide": [
          "$sumA",
          "$sumB"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

References: [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#-group--aggregation-), [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#-sum--aggregation-), [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#-project--aggregation-) and [$divide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/#-divide--aggregation-)